# How to filter Observables with other Observables

Tags: java, reactive-programming, observable

The problem I am facing is as follows:
I have two observables one is fetching data from network and the other from db. The second one might be empty but the lack of the first one is considered an error. Then if the result from network comes I need to compare it with the latest results from db ( if present ) and if they differ I want to store them ( if the db observable is empty I want to store network results anyway).

Is there any dedicated operator that handles a case like this?

So far I tried a solution with zipWith ( which is not working as expected if db is empty ), buffer ( which is working but is far from ideal ),
and I also tried flatmapping ( which requires additional casting in the subscriber ).

Below is the solution with buffer.

```
Observable.concat(ratesFromNetwork(), latestRatesFromDB())
                .buffer(3000, 2)
                .filter(buffer -> !(buffer.size() == 2 && !buffer.get(0).differentThan(buffer.get(1))))
                .map(buffer -> buffer.get(0))
                .subscribe(this::save,
                        (ex) -> System.out.println(ex.getMessage()),
                        () -> System.out.println("completed"));
```

If I modify latestRatesFromDb so that it is not returning Observable but and Optional instead the whole problem becomes trivial because I can filter using this result. It seams that there is no way to filter in an asynchronous way ( or did I miss something ?)

Comment: What do these observables emit? just one item or multiple?

Comment: Only one event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is how I would go about writing this.

Firstly, whatever class has the `differentThan` function should be changed to override `equals` instead. Otherwise you can't use a lot of basic methods with these objects.

For the purpose of this example I wrote all the observables using the `Integer` class as my type parameter. I then use a scheduler to write two mock methods:

```
static Observable<Integer> ratesFromNetwork(Scheduler scheduler) {
    return Observable.<Integer>create(sub -> {
        sub.onNext(2);
        sub.onCompleted();
    }).delay(99, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler);
}

static Observable<Integer> latestRatesFromDB(Scheduler scheduler) {
    return Observable.<Integer>create(sub -> {
        sub.onNext(1);
        sub.onCompleted();
    }).delay(99, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler);
}
```

As you can see both are similar, however, they will emit different values.

> lack of the first one is considered an error

The best way to achieve this is to use a `timeout`. You can log the error immediately here and continue:

```
final Observable<Integer> networkRate = ratesFromNetwork(scheduler)
    .timeout(networkTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler)
    .doOnError(e -> System.err.println("Failed to get rates from network."));
```

When the `timeout` fails an error will be thrown by rx. `doOnError` will give you a better idea of where this error started and let it propagate through the rest of the sequence.

> The second one might be empty

In this case I would do a similar strategy, however, do not let the error propagate by using the method `onErrorResumeNext`. Now you can make sure the observable emits at least one value by using `firstOrDefault`. In this method use some dummy value that you expect to never match with the network results.

```
final Observable<Integer> databaseRate = latestRatesFromDB(scheduler)
    .timeout(databaseTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler)
    .doOnError(e -> System.err.println("Failed to get rates from database"))
    .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
    .firstOrDefault(-1);
```

Now by using the `distinct` method you can grab a value only when it is different than the one that came before it (which is why you need to override `equals`).

```
databaseRate.concatWith(networkRate).distinct().skip(1)
    .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Updating to " + i),
        System.err::println,
        () -> System.out.println("completed"));
```

Here the database rate was placed before the network rate to take advantage of `distinct`. a `skip` is then added to always ignore the database rate value.

---

**Complete Code:**

```
final long networkTimeOut = 100;
final long databaseTimeOut = 100;

final TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();

final Observable<Integer> networkRate = ratesFromNetwork(scheduler)
    .timeout(networkTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler)
    .doOnError(e -> System.err.println("Failed to get rates from network."));

final Observable<Integer> databaseRate = latestRatesFromDB(scheduler)
    .timeout(databaseTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler)
    .doOnError(e -> System.err.println("Failed to get rates from database"))
    .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
    .firstOrDefault(-1);

databaseRate.concatWith(networkRate).distinct().skip(1)
    .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Updating to " + i),
        System.err::println,
        () -> System.out.println("completed"));

scheduler.advanceTimeBy(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

---

When `networkTimeOut` and `databaseTimeOut` are greater than 100 it prints:

```
Updating to 2
completed
```

When `networkTimeOut` is less than 100 it prints:

```
Failed to get rates from network.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

When `databaseTimeOut` is less than 100 it prints:

```
Failed to get rates from database
Updating to 2
completed
```

And if you modify `latestRatesFromDB` and `ratesFromNetwork` to return the same value, it simply prints:

```
completed
```

---

And if you don't care about forcing timeouts or logging then it boils down to:

```
latestRatesFromDB().firstOrDefault(dummyValue)
    .concatWith(ratesFromNetwork())
    .distinct().skip(1)
    .subscribe(this::save, 
        System.err::println, 
        () -> System.out.println("completed"));
```

Comment: Yeah, the last example is what I was aiming for.  Overriding equals does the job! Thanks.